# Gpath doing predicates with comparison expressions

Tags: groovy, predicate, gpath

Using Groovy 2.0

Is it possible with the GPath property expressions to uses predicate to filter:

```
class HandShaker {
String title
}

class AussieGreeter implements Greeter {
String name
List<HandShaker> handshaker
    ....
}

AussieGreeter greeter = new AussieGreeter()
greeter.setName("hello")
greeter.setHandshaker([new Handshaker().setTitle("butler")].asList()])

println Eval.x(greeter,"x[name=='hello'].handshaker[0].title")
```

To filter a Greeter if the name property is equal to "hello"?  Haven't seen an examples like this and Groovy bails with MissingPropertyException.

Comment: If this can't be done with GPath and I am not thrilled with OGNL or MVEN what to other people do?

Comment: Tested: println Eval.x(greeter,"x.find { it.name == 'hello'}.handshaker[0].title") which works, just would like the shorthand of actual predicates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do:

```
println Eval.x(greeter,"x.find { it.name == 'hello' }.handshaker[0].title")
```

You can hack the `getAt` method for `AussieGreeter` to take a Closure, and return the element if that returns `true` or `null` otherwise like so:

```
class HandShaker {
  String title
}

interface Greeter {}

class AussieGreeter implements Greeter {
  String name
  List<HandShaker> handshaker

  def getAt( Closure o ) {
    o.delegate = this
    o.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    o() ? this : null
  }
}

AussieGreeter greeter = new AussieGreeter( name:'hello',
                                           handshaker:[new HandShaker( title:'butler' )] )

greeter[ { name == 'hello' } ]?.handshaker[0].title
```

Which is closer to your original requirement (but has braces round the comparison and a `?` after the square braces)

But the `find` is much easier to read imho :-/

Comment: That is what is in my comment.  Wanted a shorthand more compact way of doing it like predicate filters in XPath.  If this exists.  Or if people opt for another alternative like JXPath instead?

Comment: @MatthewYoung Yeah, you added your second comment just after I added this answer.  There's nothing I can think of that matches your requirement

Comment: The getAt operator is what is being applied so maybe an override with the right typing might do it: greeter.metaClass.getAt = {
   String predicate -> return Eval.x(delegate,"x.find { $predicate }")
  }

Comment: @MatthewYoung Added the best I can think of for hacking around with `getAt` to my answer...